# Vue router props

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to pass data with vue router from App.vue to view (Home).
Orignial data store in data() App.vuejs and I need to pass this data to view with methods passLanguage().

```js
router
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
    props: true
  },
```

```js
app vue

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cons: 'true'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    passLanguage () {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'home', params: { data: this.cons } })
    }
  }
}
```

Home vue

```js
  created () {
    this.language = this.$route.params.data
  }
```

Error returned

```
Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/".
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using query params:

app

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'home', query: { cons: this.cons } })
```

home

```
created () {
  this.language = this.$route.query.cons
}
```